# Using a Quad to cut out a Layer?

Tags: 2d, unity, shaders

Looking for options on this, but I wanted to take a Quad (or other shape), apply a material to it, and have it cutout an entire layer, to reveal the layers below/behind it. Sort of like a portal effect.

What's the best option for this?

(This is for 2D)

Comment: Do you have a video of your desired effect? Because I have no idea what you are attempting to achieve...

Comment: Sounds like you want to subtract a layer with a mask. Correct?

Comment: Yes, Subtract with Mask. Object is not rendered, and any overlapping portion of the layer is also not rendered. So a mask that removes all rending inside the mask on that same layer. A cutout.